# Styling of radio buttons is causing forms beyond the first form on a page to become unresponsive.

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a page that displays a list of `clients` who each have a list of `interests`.  When viewing a `client`'s list of `interests` you have the option to 'Add New' which reveals a previously hidden form to add either an `interest` or `event`.

Each `client`'s list of `interests` has its own form hidden when the page loads.  These forms have radio buttons styled to look like rectangles (see css below).

The first form of each type works as expected, but the subsequent forms do not visibly respond to 'clicks' selecting an option (even if I style the radio button to be visible - they remain unselected).  However, if I click the option and click 'create' the form is submitted as if it was clicked and an appropriate `interest` is created that belongs to the selected `client`.

I have learned that when I am clicking options on a visibly unresponsive form the options on the first form are selected when I return to it.

When I remove the styling I'm using to modify the radio button behavior all forms work as desired.

Why would the css below cause unresponsiveness in subsequent forms rendered on the page?

```
/*
  Hide radio button (the round disc)
  we will use just the label to create pushbutton effect
*/
input[type=radio] {
    display:none;
    margin:10px;
}

/*
  Change the look'n'feel of labels (which are adjacent to radiobuttons).
  Add some margin, padding to label
*/
input[type=radio] + label {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    border-color: #ddd;
}
/*
 Change background color for label next to checked radio button
 to make it look like highlighted button
*/
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
   background-image: none;
    background-color:#d0d0d0;
}
```

Here's a link to a demo: https://young-chamber-6910.herokuapp.com/

Comment: this css cause unresponsiveness in subsequent forms, because inputs have the same id and when you click on label with for attribute, it find first element in page with this id and change it. You must put for each input different id and this resolve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in that part of code

```
<span class="radio">
   <input class="radio_buttons optional" id="interest_condition_new" name="interest[condition]" type="radio" value="New">
   <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="interest_condition_new">New</label>
</span>
```

in each row you have the same [id] attribute for input ; you must have different [id] in each row.

Comment: The `for` attribute is pointing to the first matching input in the DOM, makes sense.  Thanks!